# Assigning command output to a shell variable

Tags: linux, tcsh

I am trying to assign output of a cut command to a variable, however I am running into a strange problem.
I am using tcsh shell.

```
$echo $0
tcsh
```

This is the command I am running:

```
$set a=`cut -f2 -d' ' test.txt`
Missing }.    //This is the output I am getting
```

Now the file is real simple (well this is the not the file I was working on but I reduced the problem to this.)

Test.txt:

```
{ {corner
```

Thats it! This is the file. If I change the file to this:

```
{ {corner}
```

Statement works but "a" gets the following value:

```
$echo $a
corner   //Please note its not {corner} but corner
```

Hence I think that shell is trying to execute  `{corner`
 as a command and since its missing the closing brace shell complains. Does anyone have any idea why its showing this behavior? My understanding is that it should just assign the output of cut to the variable but looks like its assigning it recursively!
Newbie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to wrap it around double quotes

```
set a="`cut -f2 -d' ' test.txt`"
```

Same applies to uses such as `echo`

```
echo "$a"
```

**Output**

```
{corner
```

Comment: That won't work as OP intends it to. That will just assign "Missing }" to a.

Comment: No this works! try echo "$a" not echo $a. But I am confused as to why we have to do this?

Comment: My bad. I missed double quotes when echoing $a.

Comment: Had a similar problem and this solution didn't work for me. I tried to redirect the first line of a file into a variable using `set line1="head -1 file.csv"`, then when I ran `echo "$line1"` it printed out `head -1 file.csv`. Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Ah never mind, it works when I use `` instead of "" around the command